# SelectedTab in Compact Framework 2.0?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, compact-framework

There seems to be no SelectedTab property in TabControl in CompactFramework 2.0, only a SelectedIndex. I don't see any way to retrieve the index from a TabPage either.

Is comparing with a number the only way to see if a certain tab page is selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `SelectedIndex` should work.

Checking if a tab page is selected is done like:

```
if (tabControl.TabPages.IndexOf(yourTabPage) == tabControl.SelectedIndex)
{ 
    doSomething();
}
```

Comment: TabPages.IndexOf, perfect. Thanks a lot!